# Why instantiate class with no members?

Tags: c++, oop

I am currently working on some legacy code and have come across a class that has no members just one method.

```
class CommandClass
{
public:
  ModelData execute(std::string filter);
};
```

An instance of the class is created with 'new' just to call its function. Is there a good reason to do this or should I just change the class to a namespace?

EDIT: So based on the comments, I went back and reviewed the code. I did forget to put public: in the class but there is no virtual before the function so I don't think it can be used as an interface.

Comment: From the looks of it i'm guessing `execute` is declared `virtual` potentially making it a pseudo interface.

Comment: Possibly an abstract base class. Is it actually `virtual ModelData execute(std::string filter) = 0;`. Otherwise its just a class with one private method.

Comment: Given this class definition, you can't create it with new and then call its function, as it's private. So you need to provide more representative code.

Comment: Why is the instance created with `new`? I'd suspect it's not needed.

Comment: If this is the real code, you should scan for `friend` declarations which might explain the design.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thanks! I feel like you are right that it is not needed, but I just wanted to be sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider following template:

```
template<class T>
ModelData foo(T command) {
    auto str = "foo"s;
    return T.execute(str);
}
```

You can pass an instance of any type that has the member function `ModelData execute(std::string)` to that function. Such a type may or may not have state (member variables).

`CommandClass` may have been designed as a parameter for a similar template. Instantiating* the class would be necessary to call the templated function, even though there is no state that can be used by `execute`.

That's just one possibility. If there's no documentation, you'll have to ask the person who wrote the code.

*Without more details, I don't see a *good* reason to instantiate with `new`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You should give more context to your question.

Actually there are many reasons to have classes without having members themselves. They are used to model behavioral aspects mostly.

I'd suspect that `CommandClass` is intended to be used in a template model context, that requires the template parameter type to implement a `èxecute()` method.